# Weird java generic compiler behaviour on generic method

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to implement a pretty naive implementation of the command patern using generics

```
public abstract class Command { 
}


public interface CommandHandler<H extends Command> {

    boolean isActive();     
    void execute( H command );

}


public class CommandExecutionServiceImpl implements CommandExecutionService {

    private Map< Class<Command>,CommandHandler<Command>> commandMap; 


    public CommandExecutionServiceImpl(){       
        commandMap = new HashMap<Class<Command>, CommandHandler<Command>>();        
    }

    @Override
    public void executeCommand(Command command) {

        CommandHandler<Command> handler = commandMap.get(command.getClass());
        handler.execute(command);       

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isActive(Command command) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public <H extends Command> void addCommandHandler(Class<H> commandClass, CommandHandler<H> handler) {       

        commandMap.put( commandClass, handler );

    }
```

Compiler fails with

**Compilation failure
CommandExecutionServiceImpl.java:[36,12] put(java.lang.Class,CommandHandler) in java.util.Map,CommandHandler> cannot be applied to (java.lang.Class,CommandHandler)**

I can't understand why the compiler cannot infer the type at commandMap.put( commandClass, handler );

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want a generic relationship between the keys and values of the map. If this were supported it might look like this:

```
private <H extends Command> Map<Class<H>, CommandHandler<H>> commandMap;
```

But that's obviously not allowed. A workaround is to use Josh Bloch's [*Typesafe Heterogeneous 
Container*](http://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&lpg=PA142&ots=yYKfKiu2T-&dq=joshua%20bloch%27s%20type%20safe%20heterogeneous%20container&pg=PA142#v=onepage&q=joshua%20bloch%27s%20type%20safe%20heterogeneous%20container&f=false) pattern:

```
private Map<Class<? extends Command>, CommandHandler<? extends Command>> commandMap; 

@Override
public <H extends Command> void executeCommand(H command) {

    // addCommandHandler guarantees the safety of this unchecked cast
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    CommandHandler<H> handler = (CommandHandler<H>)commandMap.get(command.getClass());
    handler.execute(command);
}
```

Comment: actually, i don't want a generic relationship between key-value in a map but a relationship between the command class and the commandhandler type variable in the method signature , and this is working  ok. The problem here is that the compiler cannot ( I think ) cast or infer from H extends Command here:  
put(java.lang.Class<Command>,CommandHandler<Command>) in java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<Command>,CommandHandler<Command>> 
cannot be applied to (java.lang.Class<H>,CommandHandler<H>)

H extends Command so is type safe to put in a map <Class<Command>,ComandHandler<Command>>

Comment: I have to cast explicity like ...

 
`
commandMap.put((Class<Command>)commandClass, (CommandHandler<Command>) handler );`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. If you use `Map<Class<? extends Command>, CommandHandler<? extends Command>>` instead, `addCommandHandler` should compile fine without any casting. I omitted it from my example because it shouldn't have to change.

Comment: if I use `Map<Class<? extends Command>, CommandHandler<? extends Command>>`  the `handler.execute(command);` will not compile. The compiler can't cast from `<H extends Commands> to <? extends Command>`  :-(

Answer (score 1):

Your map is declared:

```
Map< Class<Command>,CommandHandler<Command>>
```

but you try to put values of type:

```
Class<H> commandClass, CommandHandler<H> handler
```

where `<H extends Command>`

Perhaps you should add a generic type to the CommandExecutionService of type `<T extends Command>` and declare the map as:

```
Map< Class<T>, CommandHandler<T>>
```

and the method:

```
public void addCommandHandler (Class<T> commandClass, CommandHandler<T> handler) { ... }
```

Comment: A `Map<Class<T>, CommandHandler<T>>` could only have one entry (two if you count the `null` key).